# PHP How to handle URL with infinite amount of parameters

Tags: php

I want to know how to handle infinite URL parameters using PHP. For example, some url can be

**example.com/products/electronic/computers/i5-4400-8gb-ram-1tb-gtx-960**

using mod_rewrite then, I would get it like this:

**example.com/products.php?param1=electronic&param2=computers&param3=i5-4400-8gb-ram-1tb-gtx-960**

So my question is:

In this case there are only 3 params. But maybe a website has 10 nested categories... How can I know how many there are?

Maybe the user goes into

**example.com/products/electronic/computers/**

so I only want to show all the products from that category, but if he goes to:

**example.com/products/electronic/**

then I want to show the subcategories, not products... so... how do I know what to show? That is, how do I know if the last parameter from the url is a category with more categories or is a category with products?

I hope I'm being clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: _“how do I know if the last parameter from the url is a category with more categories or is a category with products?”_ - if you can not derive this info from the URL structure - then you will have to go look it up in your database.

Comment: _“using mod_rewrite then, I would get it like this”_ - no, don’t start writing RewriteRules that try to cover all those specific cases. Have one general rule, that rewrites everything that does not physically exist to the PHP script, and take the URL apart in there, starting by exploding the path at `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no category and product with same name.

Then you get last element of params `end($_GET)`. It should be your product name.

Then check in DB for it: `$db->findByParams('name', $lastPart)`.

If you found - show product info.

Else search for category by this name. If category has sub-categories - show list of sub-categories, else - show list of products

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
switch(count($_GET))
{
     case 0: # error
     case 1: # show sub categories
     case 2: # show all products
     case 3: # 1 category with product
     case 4: # 2 categories
     ...
     default:
}
```